# How to have double click on title bar maximize/restore behavior?

Tags: themes, window-management, emerald

After installing Emerald theme manager, double clicking title makes the window roll up and down.

How can I restore the normal behavior of maximize/restore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to verify in two places,

1. `System` → `Preferences` → `Windows`

   Change the *Titlebar action* to *Maximize*.
2. `System` → `Preferences` → `Emerald Theme Manager` → `Emerald Settings tab`

   Change *Titlebar Double-Click Action* to *Maximize/Restore*.